# python subprocess works on local but not on server

Tags: php, python, subprocess

I am running a PHP script that takes input from an HTML form and will pass values into a python script that calls Blender and runs a python script in Blender. On the server and on my local machine I am testing with XAMPP. Below is the PHP snippet of the command. $value1 and $value2 are the input from the form earlier in the process.

```
//creating the command, and passing time and efficiency; spaces are kept in command because the quotes
$command ="$python $pyscript $value1 $value2 $blender $blenderFile $blenderScript $outputDirFull 2>&1";

//executing the command to call processing python program
exec($command, $output, $return_var);
```

Python

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess 

#read in values from PHP
value1 = sys.argv[1]
value2 = sys.argv[2]
blender = sys.argv[3]
blenderFile = sys.argv[4]
blenderScript = sys.argv[5]
outputDirFull = sys.argv[6]


#Below is the command to call Blender and run the blender file
command = blender + ' ' + blenderFile + ' -P ' + blenderScript + ' -- ' + value1 + ' ' + value2 + ' ' + outputDirFull
subprocess.call(command)
```

This process worked prior to a few minor changes made. One of those changes was 2>&1 to the exec to capture processing details. As mentioned earlier, this process works on my local machine, but is not completing on the server. It appears as if the process is frozen when I try to run it on the server.

On the server, I copied all the paths (blender/output paths) and hard-coded value 1 and 2 directly into the Python script and ran it straight from python. ran as expected doing it this way.